# How to use this query to compare with array values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

`SELECT DISTINCT email FROM table 1, table2                                  WHERE email = array value AND table1.id = table2.id`

if ($query->row()->email == $emailv)

Comment: What is your precise problem in doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about splitting your comma separated list and then running a query like this:

```
  WHERE my_column in (?,?,?,?)
```

passing (say) 4 values from your separated list in as parameters?

Comment: As in codeigniter there is a function named valid_email which validates a single email address. How the same function can be used to validate multiple email addresses entered in a text box